# How to compare single variable in a for loop?

Tags: python, loops

I made this program which takes input from user in a for loop and I have to compare and find highest and lowest among the input and on which day. I have successfully calculated average temperatures but somehow I am unable to calculate highest and lowest temperature.

```
NUMS = 4
htotal = 0
ltotal = 0
htemp = 0
ltemp = 0
f = 0
e = 0

print(">---=== Python Temperature Analyzer ===---<")
for i in range(NUMS):
    i = i + 1
    high = int(input("Enter the high value for day %d :" %i))
    low = int(input("Enter the low value for day %d:" %i))
    if low < high and high < 41 and low > -41:
        htemp = htemp+high
        ltemp = ltemp+low
        htotal = htotal + high
        ltotal = ltotal + low
        print(htotal, ltotal)
        if htemp > high :
            htemp = high
            f = i   

        if ltemp > low:
            ltemp=low
            e = i


    else:
        print("> Incorrect values, temperatures must be in the range -40 to 40, high must be greater than low. <")
        high = int(input("Enter the high value for day %d :" %i))
        low = int(input("Enter the low value for day %d:" %i ))
        htotal = htotal + high
        ltotal = ltotal + low

avghlow = ltotal/4
avghhigh = htotal/4
avgmean=(htotal+ltotal)/8


print("\nThe average (mean) LOW temperature was :",avghlow  )
print('The average (mean) HIGH temperature was: ',avghhigh)
print('The average (mean) temperature was : ', avgmean)
print('The highest temperature was ' , htemp,', on day ', f)
print('The lowest temperature was ' , ltemp,', on day ', e)
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to collect your lows and highs in two lists and then do you min/max/avg/sum calculations at the end instead of during each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got three problems:

1. You are updating `htemp`/`ltemp` as if they're the totals, not the max and min seen so far
2. You have your test reversed for `htemp` vs. `high`
3. You have bad initial values for `htemp` and `ltemp`

Fixed code (plus some minor PEP8 fixes and tweaks for style) with comments:

```
NUMS = 4
htotal = 0
ltotal = 0
htemp = -float('inf')  # Initial highest high is lowest possible number so it's replaced immediately
ltemp = float('inf')   # Reversed for lowest low
f = 0
e = 0

print(">---=== Python Temperature Analyzer ===---<")
for i in range(1, NUMS+1):  # Remove need to constantly add 1 by having the range do it for you
    # Removed accumulating in htemp/ltemp
    high = int(input("Enter the high value for day %d :" %i))
    low = int(input("Enter the low value for day %d:" %i))
    if -41 < low < high < 41:  # Python chained conditionals simplify this test a lot
        htotal += high
        ltotal += low
        print(htotal, ltotal)
        if htemp < high:  # Flipped test so we replace only when we find a new highest high
            htemp = high
            f = i   

        if ltemp > low:
            ltemp=low
            e = i
    else:
        print("> Incorrect values, temperatures must be in the range -40 to 40, high must be greater than low. <")
        high = int(input("Enter the high value for day %d :" %i))
        low = int(input("Enter the low value for day %d:" %i ))
        htotal = htotal + high
        ltotal = ltotal + low
        # Some work needed here left as an exercise

# Replace magic numbers with NUMS
avghlow = ltotal / NUMS
avghhigh = htotal / NUMS
avgmean = (htotal + ltotal) / (NUMS * 2)


print("\nThe average (mean) LOW temperature was :", avghlow)
print('The average (mean) HIGH temperature was: ', avghhigh)
print('The average (mean) temperature was : ', avgmean)
print('The highest temperature was ', htemp, ', on day ', f)
print('The lowest temperature was ', ltemp, ', on day ', e)
```

Comment: Note that this will accept out of range input in the `else` block.

Comment: @constantstranger: Yep, that's why I left `# Some work needed here left as an exercise` in there. It's clearly incomplete. In practice, I'd probably wrap the inner body of the `for` loop with a `while True:` that only `break`s once it gets valid input, moving the code handling valid input after the `while` loop. Avoids duplicating code, handles multiple failed inputs in a row properly, etc.

Comment: Makes sense. In my answer, I used a `while` loop though not a `break` statement. I wanted to make sure OP understood that what you posted may not "work perfectly" as-is, as OP's comment seemed to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Why hassle with the if loop in the first place?
Just create a list and append it  every loop. With the builtin min() and max() functions you can get your highest and lowest value. For the means you can simply add all values and divide by the list length.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your code that does what I think you are trying for:

```py
NUMS = 4
htotal = 0
ltotal = 0
htemp = 0
ltemp = 0
f = 0
e = 0

print(">---=== Python Temperature Analyzer ===---<")
for i in range(1, NUMS + 1):
    firstAttempt = True
    while firstAttempt or not (low < high and high < 41 and low > -41):
        if not firstAttempt:
            print("> Incorrect values, temperatures must be in the range -40 to 40, high must be greater than low. <")
        high = int(input("Enter the high value for day %d :" %i))
        low = int(input("Enter the low value for day %d:" %i))
        firstAttempt = False
    htotal += high
    ltotal += low
    print(htotal, ltotal)
    if htemp < high :
        htemp = high
        f = i   

    if ltemp > low:
        ltemp=low
        e = i

avghlow = ltotal / NUMS
avghhigh = htotal / NUMS
avgmean = (htotal + ltotal) / (2 * NUMS)

print("\nThe average (mean) LOW temperature was :",avghlow  )
print('The average (mean) HIGH temperature was: ',avghhigh)
print('The average (mean) temperature was : ', avgmean)
print('The highest temperature was ' , htemp,', on day ', f)
print('The lowest temperature was ' , ltemp,', on day ', e)
```

Explanation:

- The `range()` arguments in the `for` statement have been updated to start from 1
- The `if/else` logic has been replaced with a `while` loop that repeatedly queries the user at each iteration over `i` for input until valid input is provided
- The comparison of `htemp` and `high` is fixed (you had `>`, but needed `<`)
- The denominators in your calculations after the loop (`avghlow`, `avghhigh` and `avgmean`) have been changed to use `NUMS` for consistency.